# Give rules depending on percentage between two cells?

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula, percentage

I need for R5 to tell me if L5 is greater than F5 by certain percentage. For example:

```
If L5 is greater than F5 by 9.99% or less then I need R5 to = Full
If L5 is greater than F5 by 10% -  19.99% then I need R5 to = Half
```

and finally

```
If L5 is greater than F5 by 20% or greater then I need R5 to = NONE
```

Comment: This can be achieved using a simple Excel formula. What did you try already?

Comment: I haven't used any yet. I was thinking maybe IF would help but I am not sure how to use it in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming 99 does not count as greater than 100 by less than 10% IF should work:

```
=IF(AND(L5>F5,L5<=1.0999*F5),"Full",IF(AND(L5>F5,L5<=1.1999*F5),"Half",IF(L5>=1.2*F5,"NONE")))
```

without making provision for where L5 is less than F5.

Comment: Wow this is perfect! What changes do I make to formula if in case L5 is less than F5 will fall in the "Full" category or if "blank" to stay blank? Thank you!